# Wordpress: Display a widget at 100% sidebar width

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using the HTML Javascript Adder plugin to display my hotel search script and it does not fit within the sidebar area.

I need the javascript to be displayed @ 100% width of the sidebar container like the "reserve now" box just above it.

This happens when the Javascript is pasted in a standard WP text widget as well.  I assume it is just a CSS issue.

Thanks for your help in advance!

http://i213.photobucket.com/albums/cc316/ShaggyZ6/css-issue_zps541ef8ac.jpg

What I have tried that didn't work:

`.sidebar-inner div.htmljavascriptadder.widget {
    width: 100% !important;
}`

The javascript needs to be inserted into the `<div class="row-fluid">` section.

Link to the test site in question: http://gh.bestimportcarinsurance.com/

Comment: We can't diagnose from an image.

Comment: Include the relevant code (what you have tried) in your question

Comment: Sorry, the link to my test site is:

http://gh.bestimportcarinsurance.com/

I have tried using this in CSS:

.sidebar-inner div.htmljavascriptadder.widget {
 width: 100% !important;
}

But it is adjusting the background behind the javascript.

It needs to be centered in the <div class="row-fluid">

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `.htmljavascriptadder {box-sizing: border-box;}`. Problem is caused because the padding is adding to the width not being included within it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is still just adjusting the background behind the java script but not aligning the script itself.

Comment: The script is just a script, it's not outputing any html as far as I can tell?

Comment: The java script is inserted as this `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.hotelscombined.com/SearchBox/159309'></script>` The styling for that box is determined by the source I assume.

If you notice, the left side of the blue search box lines up perfectly with where the text is aligned in the "Upcoming Events" box below.  If I could just get the search box alined on the far left of the widget row I would be set.